# How to get process memory consumption in Android

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, android-emulator

I want to know the memory consumption of an application A through Application B. I am aware of all the [techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android) that have been discussed on this website. However, none of them are working for me. 
My scenario is, I have already implemented a code that can monitor CPU consumption of any specific application through top command. However, the top command only provides VSS and RSS, while i am interested in PSS and USS. One way to get these values is through procrank. However, I am not sure if procrank command can be executed on smartphone as I have tried `process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("procrank");` but its not working. (EDIT: Works on Android emulator (not smartphone).
Can someone please guide me how to get PSS and USS through Application id or name, which I have already taken through top command.

Comment: Dianne Hackborn, who is on the Android team at Google, answers this question really well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813).

Comment: Yes, I have read this article and provided a reference in my post. I am looking for some code that can provide me PSS and USS info, using memeoryinfo() or procrank on android. Can you help?

Comment: You might be better off explaining why you want to get the memory usage info for another app. I suspect there's a better tool for your use-case than whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually I am creating a profiler that will monitor applications CPU, Memory, Energy consumption and perform some actions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, I will suggest something..

- Firstly get root privilege in console with

  ```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  ```
- Then write your command with root access

  ```
  su <--command-->
  ```
- Read stream output

  ```
  try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");         
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = 
                             new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("procrank\n");             
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = 
                             new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
        byte[] bff = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
        bufferedInputStream.read(bff);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  ```

Please go through [my answer for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48885488/2553431)